# How do I pass 'event reference' to inner 'function call'?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Code:

```
$(function() {
    return $(".side-menu .nav .dropdown").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
        return $(".side-menu .nav .dropdown .collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Unintended behavior:

Outer container collapses (probably because before `shown`, he `hide` all) **sometimes** within' these milisecs between `show.bs.collapse` and `shown.bs.collapse`.

How do I pass `$(".side-menu .nav .dropdown")` that is triggering `.on(...)` to the inner function call, so I could `hide` the others? Or `hide` **only** the ones that is already `show`?

Comment: You can reference the item triggering with `this` inside the callback function to `on()` (e.g. `var $nav = $(this);`). Another item of note: drop those `return` statements. If you added code to the DOM-ready handler after what you have here, it wouldn't run because you are ending execution with `return`. Also, `show.bs.collapse` is fired when the element *starts* to be shown, not *after* it is shown. You may want to use `shown.bs.collapse` instead.

Comment: It's running fine. As I said: this code execution is causing the unintended behavior (so, it's running) when it hides all `.collapse`'s before ending the `show` to `shown` (the call is on `show` as you can see) transition, what causes the outter container to "close" (because there are no items expanded for these milisecs).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    $(".side-menu .nav .dropdown").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
        //find all the dropdown, exclude the one that was just
        //shown, and hide them
        $(".side-menu .nav .dropdown").not(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually this worked. Thanks. And I tried to change the `show.bs.collapse` to `shown.bs.collapse` within your suggestion, **but** my outter container still is closing even with one `<li>` still showing... so I'll do some more searching in this code I'm reviewing...